# Integration Test with Couchbase container

Tags: containers, couchdb, integration-testing

I am writing an integration test, which should use a couchbase container.
Using `org.testcontainers.couchbase.CouchbaseContainer` with

```
 @Rule

public CouchbaseContainer couchbaseContainer = new CouchbaseContainer()
            .withNewBucket(DefaultBucketSettings.builder()
                    .enableFlush(true)
                    .name("xxx").password("123456")
                    .quota(100)
                    .type(BucketType.COUCHBASE)
                    .build());
```

I get an error:
Caused by: com.couchbase.client.java.error.InvalidPasswordException: Passwords for bucket "xxx" do not match.
    at com.couchbase.client.java.CouchbaseAsyncCluster$OpenBucketErrorHandler.call(CouchbaseAsyncCluster.java:651)

When I looked inside the container, I could see that bucket whose created without the user. (In order to be able to use that bucket, a user, with the same name must be created, and user's password is actually password to enter the bucket).
While not providing UserSettings, withNewBucket method generates user with all roles. I tried to add custome UserSettings, but the result was the same - user wasn't created.

Using

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.couchbase.client</groupId>
   <artifactId>couchbase-client</artifactId>
   <version>1.4.13</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
        <artifactId>testcontainers</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
        <artifactId>couchbase</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

 <dependency>
  <groupId>com.couchbase.client</groupId>
   <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.9</version>
 </dependency>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It was dependencies issue. I started from scratch, and it just worked.